# How do I control optical zoom in a running "Internet Explorer_Server" instance?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, automation

Windows Live Writer hosts an Internet Explorer control for editing, but there's no zoom control. I'd like to be able to send a zoom command to it. Since other apps host the IE browser, I'd think a utility that can send zoom commands to specific IE browser instances would be really handy, but I haven't found one.

I've seen there's a command, [OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I'm not sure how to send that command to it. Ideally I'd like to do this from C# or Powershell.

**Note**: The question is asking about controlling the zoom in a web browser control in a running application which I did not create, the main example being the editor surface in Windows Live Writer.

Comment: Geoff Norton linked to cEXWB (http://www.google.ca/codesearch/p?hl=en#Y0QumTMIokc/cEXWB.cs&q=OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM&sa=N&cd=17&ct=rc) which shows an example once you have an IOleCommandTarget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short version: I'm not entirely sure you can do what you're attempting to do.**

I have some code that actually gets a handle on the HTML document inside the WLW window, and that works, but what I'm finding is that I can't actually get a reference to the parent window of the document. I'm no native Windows guy, but I've done some PInvoke in my time. It may be just that my lack of native Windows knowledge is stopping me from bridging that last gap.

From what I've put together, the general process for getting a reference to an IE window is:

1. Get a reference for the top-level window.
2. Find the window containing the HTML document in there (recursive search).
3. Get the HTML document object from that window.
4. Get the parent window of the HTML document (which is the IE window).

Once you have that parent window, you can call the IWebBrowser2.ExecWB method to run your OLE zoom command.

**The problem is that the IHTMLDocument2.parentWindow property always seems to throw an InvalidCastException** when you try to access it. From [what](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/msie-7-0-fails-return-document-parentwindow-net-help-99621242.html) I've [read](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=434117), that's the deal when you try to grab the parent window from a thread other than the one the document is running on.

So, anyway, I'll drop the code on you that gets the HTML document reference and if you can bridge that tiny last step of the way, you'll have your answer. I just couldn't figure it out myself.

This is a console app. You'll need a reference to Microsoft.mshtml for the IHTMLDocument2 interface.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ControlInternetExplorerServer
{
    ////////////////////////
    // LOTS OF PINVOKE STUFF
    ////////////////////////

    [Flags]
    public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
    {
        SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0,
        SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1,
        SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
        SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8
    }

    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(
            string lpClassName,
            string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(
            IntPtr hwndParent,
            IntPtr hwndChildAfter,
            string lpszClass,
            string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "GetWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetNextWindow(IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int wFlag);

        [DllImport("oleacc.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
        public static extern object ObjectFromLresult(
            IntPtr lResult,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid refiid,
            IntPtr wParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
            IntPtr windowHandle,
            uint Msg,
            IntPtr wParam,
            IntPtr lParam,
            SendMessageTimeoutFlags flags,
            uint timeout,
            out IntPtr result);

        public static IntPtr FindWindowRecursive(IntPtr parent, string windowClass, string windowCaption)
        {
            var found = FindWindowEx(parent, IntPtr.Zero, windowClass, windowCaption);
            if (found != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return found;
            }

            var child = FindWindowEx(parent, IntPtr.Zero, null, null);
            while (child != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                found = FindWindowRecursive(child, windowClass, windowCaption);
                if (found != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return found;
                }
                child = GetNextWindow(child, 2);
            }
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }


    //////////////////////
    // THE INTERESTING BIT
    //////////////////////

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // First parameter is the class name of the window type - retrieved from Spy++
            // Second parameter is the title of the window, which you'll
            // probably want to take in via command line args or something.
            var wlwWindow = NativeMethods.FindWindow("WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d", "Untitled - Windows Live Writer");
            if (wlwWindow == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to locate WLW window.");
                return;
            }

            // Since you don't know where in the tree it is, you have to recursively
            // search for the IE window. This will find the first one it comes to;
            // ostensibly there's only one, right? RIGHT?
            var ieWindow = NativeMethods.FindWindowRecursive(wlwWindow, "Internet Explorer_Server", null);
            if (ieWindow == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to locate IE window.");
                return;
            }

            // Get a handle on the document inside the IE window.
            IntPtr smResult;
            var message = NativeMethods.RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
            NativeMethods.SendMessageTimeout(ieWindow, message, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, out smResult);
            if (smResult== IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to locate the HTML document object.");
            }

            // Cast the document to the appropriate interface.
            var htmlDoc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)NativeMethods.ObjectFromLresult(smResult, typeof(mshtml.IHTMLDocument2).GUID, IntPtr.Zero);

            // Here's where you would normally get htmlDoc.parentWindow and call ExecWB
            // to execute the zoom operation, but htmlDoc.parentWindow throws an InvalidCastException.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy....

You need to override the normal web browser control by creating a derived class.

That derived class, is then used to access the underlying activeX implementation of the parent web browser control, at which point you are able to access the 'ExecWB' method which is sadly not exposed publicly in the standard object.

Once you have this underlying object, you can simply then just provide any public methods you wish, for things like zoom, then pass those directly into the activeX interface.

I've written a smaple winforms program to show how it's done, I've uploaded the project to my MSN sky drive here:

[Web browser zoom](http://1drv.ms/1zGlljT)

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but I want to control the zoom of an external web browser control. In the main example, I want to control the zoom of the editor surface in Windows Live Writer.

Comment: The guy wrote an example project and provided it... I don't think he deserves the downvote.  "A" (or at least neutral) for effort, in my opinion.  +1

Comment: I didn't downvote. I didn't mark as answer since this doesn't address the problem - controlling zoom in an external IE browser control.

Answer (score 1):

Iv'e been thinking about this, and it occurs to me that we could use an old technique from the Win32 days (Pre OLE, COM+ and all that jazz) called 'Sendkeys'

Essentially what you need to do is use the win32 API to find the window handle of the live writer main window, then from there traverse the object hierarchy of the app until you find the web control.

Once you have the handle to that object (spy++ will show you if it's accessible or not) you should in theory be able to then send any key combination you like to it, which in turn would get handled by the apps message pump as though the key press originated from the app itself.

I did have a look at trying the approach, but it does depend on the app itself actually handling and acting on a key press to perform the required function in it's code.  As I've found out by testing it, there appears to be no handling code in the parent app that does react to the zoom, so I'm not sure if the approach would work.

However, expanding on this a little, It's not difficult to write plug-ins for live writer, once you have the SDK, so I think the avenue to explore to solve this problem will be a mixture of:

A Live writer plug in to accept commands sent from a remote agent

A remote agent using a method along the same lines as send keys to send messages to the plugin

Code in the plugin, based on the code in my sample project that finds the browser control in situ, then calls it's zoom methods where needed.

I've not got time however to peruse this at the moment :-(

Comment: I don't think sendkeys will work. I'll probably need to use ExecWB or SendMessage.

Comment: Send Message makes sense, Iv'e just been reading through the code given above, and I have to concur , that it's a cross thread problem ... however If we are sure that there is some mechanisim in the app (Either by a plug in or otherwise) Then SendMessage makes perfect sense.